# Strange issue with composer.phar - deletes available files

Tags: composer-php

My Composer.phar runs into an error:

```
Composer.phar - UnexpectedValueException - Invalid Zip error
```

I've tried the following solutions:

1. Cleared the cache
2. Used '--prefer-source'

No luck!

I manually downloaded the file that is required for the setup and placed it in the necessary folder. But the install again tries to download the file and fails with the same error. Besides, it also deletes the file I manually placed!

Is there something else I need to do to pass this step? Is there a way I can force Composer to skip the files which are already available?

Comment: Can you add the minimal needed `composer.json` that is able to reproduce the problem? Like "Only the one single public package that has that problem, standalone"?

Comment: I checked the `composer.json` file, it doesn't mention anything related to that file. Can you please tell me which part exactly do you require me to paste?

Comment: You are talking about "the file", which means you know which package is affected. Can you create a composer.json file in a new empty project with only that package required, and see if the same error is thrown?